# Yes/No-form on fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

My question is, how to determine if user press to 'yes' or 'no'
Here is a html

```
<form id="delFrm" method="post">
    <label>Do you want delete?</label>
    <input type="submit" name="yes" id="yes" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="no" id="no" value="no" />
</form>
```

and here is jquery/js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#delFrm').submit(function(){
            var yes = true;//how to define it??????
            if(yes) {
                //sent ajax to delete the data
            } else {
                //close close the form on a fancybox
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Change slightly your markup: since the 'no' button doesn't need to perform an ajax call you could simply write

```
<form id="delFrm" method="post">
    <label>Do you want delete?</label>
    <input type="submit" name="yes" id="yes" value="yes" />
    <button type="button" id="no">No</button>
</form>
```

and your js code could be simplified as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#delFrm').submit(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            //sent ajax to delete the data
        });
    });
</script>
```

then create another handler for the 'no' button (which closes your fancybox)

Comment: And add a callback function to 'no' button click handler to close the fancybox

Comment: yep @roasted just inserted as final note :)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to change your html just do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answer = "";
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       answer = $(this).attr('name');
        if(asnwer == 'yes') {
            // sent ajax to delete the data
        } else {
            // close close the form on a fancybox
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

It is simple like this..

Comment: e.preventDefault(); alert($(this).attr('name')); shows "undefined", what is "this" and 'name'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have to call execute some statements to close the ajax form:

```
<form id="delFrm" method="post">
    <label>Do you want delete?</label>
    <input type="submit" name="yes" id="yes" value="yes" />
    <input type="button" name="no" id="no" value="no" />
</form>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#delFrm').submit(function(){

            //sent ajax to delete the data

            return false;
        });
        $('#no').click(function(){

            //close close the form on a fancybox

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)